# Objective-C Custom Class Actions and Outlets

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, uiview, iboutlet

I am attempting to create a custom subclass of a UIView as follows:

I created a .xib with a UIView that contains a Picker object and Toolbar object, hooked up the Outlets and actions.

[image]

CustomPickerView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomPickerView : UIView

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIDatePicker* datePicker;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem* doneButton;

-(IBAction) buttonDonePush:(id)sender;

@end
```

CustomPickerView.m

```
#import "CustomPickerView.h"

@implementation CustomPickerView

-(id) init
{
    self=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomPickerView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    return self;
}

-(void) buttonDonePush:(id)sender
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"CustomPickerViewDoneButtonPush" object:nil userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:self.datePicker.date forKey:@"date"]];
}

@end
```

And finally, in my ViewController I instantiate the object in the viewDidLoad method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.customPickerView=[[CustomPickerView alloc] init];
    self.customPickerView.datePicker.datePickerMode=UIDatePickerModeTime;

    self.dateField.inputView=self.customPickerView;
}
```

When the user taps on the self.dateField, my CustomPickerView pops up nicely in place of the standard keyboard.

The problem is when the user taps the Done button from my CustomPickerView class, the buttonDonePush action does not fire.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't fire? Have you added the controller as an observer of that notification?

Comment: have you set the target for the doneButton to the outlet?

Comment: `self=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomPickerView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];` The xib's owner is nil because self is not initialized.

Comment: Why don't you use a delegate, instead of overkill/inappropriate notification?

Comment: See the comments beneath my answer.

Comment: Yep the Received Action "buttonDonePush" has been set to the Bar Button Item in IB. I know it is not being called because I stepped through the code. I apologize if my post was unclear but this question has nothing to do with Notifications.

Comment: @MikeM Yes I did. I stepped through the code and the action didn't fire. This really isn't a newbie question (I don't think)... It relates to another post I made recently here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516318/storyboard-and-xib-use-in-same-project) Any insight you have would be helpful.

Comment: You set a breakpoint in buttonDonePush, or added an NSLog there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer can be considered as the iOS companion to a similar solution I offered recently for iOSX:

[Interface-Builder: "combine" NSView-class with .xib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18353751/interface-builder-combine-nsview-class-with-xib/18410756#18410756)

Your arrangement is thus:

- Mainstoryboard.storyboard
- MyViewController.h
- MyViewController.m
- CustomPickerView.xib
- CustomPickerView.h
- CustomPickerView.m

You want to use your customPickerView as a subview of MyViewController.view and want to be able to access it's control widgets from the containing context.

In your example you are creating the customPickerView in code, but another useful scenario is to add it to the storyboard in Interface Builder. This solution will work for both scenarios.

In CustomViewPicker.h

- declare IBOutlets for your interface elements. You have already done this for your datePicker and doneButton, but you also need an IBOutlet to a UIView which will be the containing view for these items.

  ```
  @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView* view;
  ```

In CustomViewPicker.xib

- Set the file's owner class to CustomViewPicker in the Identity Inspector.
- Set the top-level view in the xib to the defaul UIView class (*NOT* CustomViewPicker).
- Connect your IBOutlets from the file's owner: `view`, `datePicker`, `doneButton` to their respective IB objects
- Connect your IBAction from the file's owner: `buttonDonePush` to the `doneButton` IB object

In CustomViewPicker.m:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    //called when initialising in code
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self initialise];
    }
    return self;
}

  - (void)awakeFromNib
  {
      //called when loading from IB/Storyboard
      [self initialise];
  }

- (void) initialise
{
    NSString* nibName = NSStringFromClass([self class]);
    if ([[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibName
                                      owner:self
                                    options:nil]) {
        [self.view setFrame:[self bounds]];
        [self addSubview:self.view];
    }

}
-(void) buttonDonePush:(id)sender
{
   //button push actions
}
```

If you want to initialise in code (as you have done), your MyViewController would contain something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 300);
    self.customPickerView=[[CustomPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

    self.customPickerView.datePicker.datePickerMode=UIDatePickerModeTime;
    self.dateField.inputView=self.customPickerView;
}
```

[*edit* removed this redundant line: `[self.view addSubview:self.customPickerView];`]

Alternatively you can create your CustomPickerView - and set it's frame - directly in the storyboard. Just add a custom view to your MyViewController's storyboard scene, and change it's class to CustomPickerView. Link it to your `self.customPickerView` IBOutlet.

In this case `initWithFrame` does not get called, but `awakeFromNib` is invoked when  MyViewController loads it's CustomPickerView subview. Your MyViewController's `viewDidLoad` would then look like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.customPickerView.datePicker.datePickerMode=UIDatePickerModeTime;
    self.dateField.inputView=self.customPickerView;
}
```

If you want to get your button push action out of the customPickerView, you might consider using a delegate, which could be  more self-contained than your use of NSNotification (but that issue reaches beyond your original question).

Comment: Your code worked except the [self.view addsubView:self.customPickerView] in the viewDidLoad method was not necessary. Once I implemented it as you explained, I was able quickly address the other issues I was having. By the way, the reason I was using notifications from the CustomPickerView is because I was having trouble accessing object properties between the ViewController and the CustomPickerView. I was able to get everything working perfectly because of your help. Thank You!!

Comment: @DanCooley Glad to be of help. And thanks for asking the question, I was looking for a chance to document this. It is _not_ a Newbie issue, and is something very poorly documented by Apple (or elsewhere). I've corrected that redundant line, although without it I don't understand how the view gets attached to the viewController's view (it does, and the view hierarchy seems correct, I just don't understand _how_ it does).

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

An answer above pointed this out, but in the init method you are setting self, but this happens before self is ever initialized. If you could show the code where you are creating this specific view, it would help a lot. Here's my suggestion.

In your class that is controlling the deployment of this custom view:

```
//to invoke your view
CustomPickerView *myView;
NSArray *xibContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CustomPickerView" owner:nil options:nil];
for (id xibObject in xibContents) {
    if ([xibObject isKindOfClass:[CustomPickerView class]]) {
        myView = (CustomPickerView *)xibObject;
        break;
    }
}
//now *myView is instantiated as your custom picker view
//do what you want here, add to subview, set frame, etc
```

In the CustomPickerView.m file, remove the init method.

PREVIOUS ANSWER:

You are using NSNotificationCenter in this implementation. When a user touches the done button, an `NSNotification` is posted. You must explicitly "opt in" and "listen" for these notifications. You do that by registering with the notification center.

In viewDidLoad:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(receivedNotification:) 
    name:@"CustomPickerViewDoneButtonPush"
    object:nil];
```

Then you need to implement the selector you specified up there:

```
-(void)receivedNotification:(NSNotification *)note {
    NSDictionary *obj = [note object];
    NSLog(@"%@",obj);
    //dismiss the date picker here...
    //etc...
}
```

Comment: This might be it.  But I'd better tell that a notification is a weird thing to use here, most probably; a delegate is more appropriate.

Comment: I agree that the notification is weird to use here, for the same reason that a delegate would also be weird: this is all in the same class, there's no reason he can't call this method on self instead of posting a notification

Comment: Thanks but that's really not the question. The question is why isn't the -(IBAction) buttonDonePush method being called when the user taps on the Done button? Once that is called, the notification will fire and I'll handle that event elsewhere.

Comment: I see. Where do you wire up the UIBarButton item to this IBAction? Just linking the IBOutlet with the button is not enough, you also have to tell the button it should call the selector in question when a user taps it.

Comment: @JustinAmberson I wire it up in Interface Builder. Set Received Action "buttonDonePush" to Bar Button Item from toolbar. Check out the image above. This whole thing is a little bit tricky since I am using Storyboard for my ViewController and a .xib to model the CustomPicker. There has to be some kind of instantiation misunderstanding on my part.

Comment: See my new edit. Can you copy and paste where you are "creating" this custom view and deploying it? I have a feeling you are just calling `MyCustomView *view = [[MyCustomView alloc] init];` which I think is wrong. Also notice that I set the `owner:` parameter to `nil`. Clear out the File's Owner stuff in your storyboard, make the UIView object a class of CustomPickerView and then wire up the outlets to that.

Comment: @JustinAmberson Thanks for your help. See He Was solution above and my note. Problem solved :)